# Landsat / MODIS spatio-temporal fusion: STARFM and software implementations

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, modis

My main goal is to create Landsat/MODIS image pairs, perform an spatial-temporal fusion which leads to synthetic composites on dates between Landsat acquisition dates.

This brought me to the paper by Gao, and the STARFM software. However, the only software implementation of STARFM or derivatives seems to be the executable from the USDA (https://www.ars.usda.gov/research/software/download/?softwareid=432).

I cannot find any other software implementation of STARFM or derivative, neither on GitHub, R/Python, or elsewhere. Does anyone know of any other software implementations of these Spatio-temporal fusion models?

Answer (score 5):

If you click the "Take me to the download..." button in the page you linked, it will eventually lead you to the download link for the [full StarFM distribution](https://www.ars.usda.gov/ARSUserFiles/80420510/software/432/StarFM_v1.2.2_full.tar.gz).

Upon extracting that file, you will find StarFM's source under `StarFM/source`.

Also, you can find a CUDA implementation of the algorithm on GitHub at https://github.com/HPSCIL/cuSTARFM.

Comment: It seems that neither of them can be run in Windows OS. Do you have any workaround beside installing Linux OS?